# sqlsrv reset pointer to first without getting record

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I loop through an sqlsrv result set with a `while` loop

```
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_set) ) {
 ...  do stuff ...
}
```

Later in my code I want to loop through result set again with `while` but I don't know how to reset to FIRST without getting a record.

This will reset the pointer, but also gets a record and moves the pointer:

```
sqlsrv_fetch($result_s4, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST);
```

I don't want it to fetch a record! I want to prepare another while loop with the same dataset. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
   while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_set, SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST) ) {

}
```

How do I reset the pointer but not fetch a record in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To note I am using this style of cursor in the sqlsrv_query call:

```
$conn_cursor = array("Scrollable" => 'buffered');    
$result_set = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $conn_cursor);
```

I was able to trick and reset the pointer to the first record again without fetching an actual data row like this:

```
sqlsrv_fetch($result_set, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, -1);
```

Now I can while loop through it again.